# Can third-party devs control HomePod remotely?

Tags: ios, airplay, homepod

In iOS, you can remotely-control a HomePod via Control Center, the Music app, and Apple’s Podcasts app.

If a third-party developer wanted to send an iTunes podcast episode or an Apple Music item to a HomePod, could they build similar in-app controls like Music or Podcasts?

*(Yes, I know that I can use AirPlay to stream audio to a HomePod - but that’s not quite the same as the UI shown below...)*

I expect that there’s not a way for a third-party app to implement such a control - but I’d love to know if it is!

[image: HomePod controls in Music and Podcast apps]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there's no public API for this. I think it's currently implemented by the private framework MediaRemote.framework.